# 301 Redirect - variable in the old url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, http-status-code-301

I have several urls on a Joomla site which have been indexed and I need to 301 redirect them into some new pages. The old URL is formed like this:

http://www.mydomain.com/en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english?start=20

I want it to go to:

http://www.mydomain.com/en/family-members/family-disease

I tried using:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english$ http://www.www.mydoamin.com/en/family-members/family-disease%1 [R=301,L]
```

I've tried several answers on here but nothing seems to be working.

[htaccess 301 redirect dynamic url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513164/htaccess-301-redirect-dynamic-url)

and

[301 Redirecting URLs based on GET variables in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871511/301-redirecting-urls-based-on-get-variables-in-htaccess)

Any ideas what I should try next? (I've tried a normal redirect 301)

Comment: Post your best guess at a solution as a starting point.

Comment: I tried using:


`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^start=(.*)$

RewriteRule ^/en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english$ http://www.www.mydoamin.com/en/family-members/family-disease%1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Check out this: [Adapting Custom URLs with .htaccess or tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634494/joomla-2-5-adapting-custom-urls-with-htaccess-or-tool/15654818#15654818). More convenient than messing with .htaccess

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I tried using the tool in joomla and that has not worked to forward the user to the desired url.

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it. You need to remove the leading slash from your rule's pattern because it's removed from the URI when applying rules from an htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english$ /en/family-members/family-disease%1? [R=301,L]
```

You also don't need the `http://www.www.mydoamin.com` bit (2 sets of `www`). At the end of your target, you have `family-disease%1`, which means if `start=20` then the end of your URL will look like: `family-disease20`. Is that right?

Comment: I don't really want the 20 at the end of the redirected url.

Comment: @AndrewMatthews then remove the `%1` at the end

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the reply. I've tried your rule and the redirect isn't working. I also left it on to check it was working and there was still no redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The new URL doesn't have the query string in it, so it is just stripping of the last URL path part. If you want it hardcoded

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=
RewriteRule ^en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english$ /en/family-members/family-disease? [R,L]
```

or a little bit more flexible

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=
RewriteRule ^en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/.+$ /en/family-members/family-disease? [R,L]
```

or if you just want to keep two levels after `en/wfmenuconfig`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=
RewriteRule ^en/wfmenuconfig/(.+?/.+?)/ /en/$1? [R,L]
```

Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redirect `http://www.mydomain.com/en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english?start=$var` into `http://www.mydomain.com/en/family-members/family-disease`, then you must try these directives:

```
# once per .htaccess file
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} start=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english /en/family-members/family-disease [R=301,L]
```

But if that's not what you want, but to redirect `http://www.mydomain.com/en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english?start=$var` into `http://www.mydomain.com/en/family-members/family-disease$var` then you could check this one:

```
# once per .htaccess file
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} start=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english /en/family-members/family-disease%1 [R=301,L]
```

---

Now, give this one a little more try if it will work. If it's not, then find any suspicious why this code is not working:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /en/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} start=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english /family-members/family-disease [R]
```

And go to `http://www.mydomain.com/en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english?start=$AnyNumber` if it's redirecting into `http://www.mydomain.com/en/family-members/family-disease` just make sure that your web server have **mod_rewrite**.

Comment: @AndrewMatthews Please try it again, for I've already revised it.

Comment: Hi Servant,Thanks for your time, I tried again but it didn't work.

Comment: @AndrewMatthews What is the exact folder where */en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english* is located? And why it have no file extension, such *.php*?

Comment: en is the language code that joomla assigns to the url. the urls are set to be sef so joomla removes the extension from them.

Comment: @AndrewMatthews What do you want to do? To redirect `http://www.mydomain.com/en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-english?start=$var` into `http://www.mydomain.com/en/family-members/family-disease` or to redirect it into `http://www.mydomain.com/en/family-members/family-disease$var`?

Comment: http://www.mydomain.com/en/wfmenuconfig/family/family-disease/177-category-engl‌​ish?start=$var into http://www.mydomain.com/en/family-members/family-disease

Comment: @AndrewMatthews Last try on my updates, if it's not work. You must give some suspicious why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to throw this out there, I was also having trouble getting the RewriteRule to work. I have a client that upgraded to a WordPress powered site from .asp pages. What I had to do to get this to work is insert the RewriteCond and RewriteRule in the htaccess file BEFORE the "# BEGIN WordPress" section. Now it works just as it should.

This is posted way late, but hopefully it helps someone else out there running into the same issue.

Doesn't Work:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var=somestring$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.asp$ http://www.domain.com/newpage? [R=301,L]
```

Does Work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var=somestring$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.asp$ http://www.domain.com/newpage? [R=301,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Order of operations must be important =)